# How to trigger function for jquery selectable list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code where I implement a selectable buttons just like in the demo of jquery ui(http://jqueryui.com/selectable/). I want to trigger a function whenever an item is selected(Item 1, Item 2, etc). I have made several attempts, but nothing works. Could someone give me a help with this.
I tried this:

```
$(".ui-selected ~ li").click(function() {
alert("hello");
});
```

also this one

```
$("#selectable li").live('click',function() {
alert("hello");
});
```

I have exactly this, but with other naming. What I want is to call a function when any 'selectable' item is selected.

```
    <style>
  #feedback { font-size: 1.4em; }
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content">Item 7</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected), you need to bind a handler to the `selectableselected` event. For instance:

```
$("#selectable").on('selectableselected',function(event, ui) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: This method worked, and it requires less code. One more question, why does this selector does not work? $("#selectable li").on("selectableselected", function(event, ui){.....

Comment: @Joel -- The selectable plugin is applied to the parent of a group of elements and not its children so it makes sense that you attach an event listener to that element and not its children.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '#selectable li', function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

This needs to be inside the .ready encapsulation of course :)

```
$(function() {
   // Right here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you can run a function when the select (or unselect) happens:

```
$(function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable({
selected: function (event, ui) {
         alert('!')
    },
unselected: function (event, ui) {
       //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This fiddle works for me, are you sure you're adding the following in your head? You can change the css, but those .js files need to be present.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RHUMv/